# Return duplicate values in array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates

I am trying to sort out an array and returning the duplicate values. So i know if the value in this case a date exists one or more times. I have been searching and I do only find how to delete the values.

I would like to just return the value that exists one or more times in the array.

This far I have come so long:

```
var singelbokningar = [];
   $.each(bokadeDatumDone, function(i, el){
   if($.inArray(el, singelbokningar) > -1) singelbokningar.push(el);
});
```

But it returns a new array without the duplicates.

How should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create another array to hold you duplicates:

```
var singelbokningar = [];
var duplicates = [];

$.each(bokadeDatumDone, function(i, el) {
   if ( $.inArray(el, singelbokningar) > -1 ) singelbokningar.push(el);
   else duplicates.push(el);
});
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you! 

There is only one problem with our code and that is:

It should be: ===1 Not > 1

But That is my fault! But thank you!